# how to make a shadow on the top of the DIV only

Tags: css

how to make a shadow on the top of the DIV only, using Box-Shadow using css3 ?

I want to modify this css3 code .. to do that

```
 box-shadow:0px 0px 45px #08C;;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 45px #08C;

    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px 15px #08C;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the prefixes for box-shadow anymore, actually. Plain `box-shadow` works in the newer browsers.

Anyhow, the syntax is (for example):

```
box-shadow: 0px -12px 12px -7px black;
```

Where 0px is *x*, -12px is *y*, 12px is the amount of blur and -7px is the *spread*. It's spread that allows you to create this effect.

See it in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/c6QLC/